# Is there a way to update the value of a Python dictionary but not add the key if it doesn't exist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary as such:

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

I want to update the value of key `'c'` and can do that with `d['c'] = 30`.

The behavior I want is to only be able to update existing keys, not add new keys. If I try to do `d['e'] = 4` I would like it to throw some kind of exception instead of the default behavior which is to create a new key `'e'` with value `4`.

Is there a function that does such behavior? I know I can do a comprehension to first check `if 'e' in d` but again, checking if there's a built-in.

Comment: probably best not to use a dictionary

Comment: You could create your own dictionary class, or create a function for this, like `def add_only(dictionary, key, value)`

Comment: It's not runtime checking, but your scenario *might* be better covered [by `typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict) with static checking rather than runtime checking. Or for runtime restrictions, by using a simple [`__slots__`-ed](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) class (and/or a simple [`dataclasses.dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)) and using attribute syntax, not `dict`-style subscripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of such behavior built-in, but you could always implement your own dict:

```py
class no_new_dict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            super().__setitem__(key, value)
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

d = no_new_dict({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
print(d)
d['c'] = 20
print(d)
d['d'] = 20
```

The output of the above snippet will be:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 20}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tomerk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 12, in <module>
    d['d'] = 20
  File "C:\Users\tomerk\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\test.py", line 6, in __setitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'd'
```